# Arduino communication with c#

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

i'm new to this community, and i have a big interest in programming as well as electronics. so I've got a problem with communication  between arduino and c# windows application.
I know how to automatically update data from serial port in console application, but in the form application for me it's pretty tricky.
So.. in arduino i have a basic sketch for reading an analog signal from a potentiometer, and in a c# application i made a ComboBox for selecting a port, and a CheckBox which makes a while loop. In a while loop I've got commands for reading the signal and display it to a user.
And sorry for my English, i'm not very good at it..
code:

namespace arduinoRead
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        serialPort1.PortName = ports.ToString();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Selected1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Jūs esat izvēlējies: '{0}' Portu", Selected1));
        serialPort1.PortName = Selected1;
        serialPort1.Open();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            label1.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1. I cant see any `while loop`. 2. What means `its tricky`? You should provide some code how far you've got and for sure a bit more details about `whats wrong`.

Comment: Apart from that `what to do`: If its working via serial port, whats the deal with a forms-app? You can use the console in a forms app just as much in a console-app!?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question with code examples. There's not really a lot here for anyone to work with to help you. You may also want to check out http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you post your code. In general, in C# form application you need to create an instance of serial port

```
        SerialPort COM = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200);
        COM.Open();
```

Then you use `COM.Write` to send bytes to the port, and `COM.Read` to read. On the Arduino side, you use `Serial.begin(115200)` (make sure the speed matches), and then `Serial.read` and `Serial.print`.

You may also want to have a look at [Windows Remote Arduino](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/04/what-is-windows-remote-arduino-and-what-can-it-do/) project, which allows you to control inputs/outputs of Arduino from C# program in a natural way. You need to put Firmata sketch on your Arduino, and then Windows Remote Arduino library handles all serial communication. See the sample project [here](https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US/windowsiot/basic-windows-remote-arduino-47eeb9).

Comment: after playing around the code, i made it close enough to the real time, and now everything works as i wanted. :) Thank you!

Comment: @equin0xy I am glad it was helpful. I suggest you also mark the answer as correct answer, so that it is more visible and helpful for other people.